# Visual Studio/IIS Express Intermittent Bugs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, iis-express

I've been having problems with IIS Express for the past few years since we stopped using regular IIS in our projects.  We typically have solutions that have a web service and some kind of client(web, desktop, or both).  When I run the client about 1 in every 10 times, I will get an error about not finding localhost:blahblah or not being able to load an assembly.  A full rebuild always fixes this problem.  HOWEVER, this is something that I have dealt with in VS2013 and VS2015 along with my coworkers.  I have come up with a workaround where I added a Pre-build event to delete the bin folder of the web service and do and msbuild on it.  This works great on my machine.  However, I don't know a way to write it where it works on our build server or on other peoples machines.  The Pre-build events get checked into source control as part of the cs.proj file so I need a generic solution if I go that route.  Here is my Pre-build script:

```
DEL /Q "C:\TFS\Enterprise Data Management\Vendor\Dev-Phase2US\WcfService\bin\*.*"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\TFS\Enterprise Data Management\Vendor\Dev-Phase2US\WcfService\WcfService.csproj"
```

Has anyone else had similar problems?  Any good solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Set an environment variable on each developers' machine and use the variable in your checked in files. Then every machine can set it to a different value based on the developer preference.

Comment: @LexLi That is a good suggestion.  I thought about that.  One drawback of that is we try to have everything in source control.  So any developer can pull the code down and run it without any environment setup.  Also, I don't think that would fly with our build server admin.  However, without my organizational restrictions, that is a great idea.

Comment: So to make sure I understand the correction correctly: you want to run this PreBuild command on every dev's machine, but need it to know the path to C:\TFS\..\Dev-Phase2US\WcfService?

Comment: @Al-Muhandis Correct.  Including the builder server.  This may not be going down the right path, but this script is the only thing I have found to solve the problem.

Comment: In that case it's really easy. I can't post the full text here so I'll add an answer. It seems to me that there's some other underlying build problem if you're getting missing assembly errors. You can diagnose what they are by setting the MSBuild output to detailed or diagnostic (/v:diagnostic, or in VS Options). There's also the Fusion logs.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis Great, I will try that.  The assembly not found problem is only happening in one solution.  The the backend localhost not firing up properly is a problem I've been having for a while in various solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to the question being asked, to use "generic" paths, use the "Macros" offered in Visual Studio (technically, MSBuild Properties). Assuming the WcfService folder is in the same solution,

```
DEL /Q "$(SolutionDir)\WcfService\bin\*.*"
```

Or if it's in some path relative to the project,

```
DEL /Q "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\WcfService\bin\*.*"
```

Note that using Pre-Build events for this is pretty bad practice though. It's better to use the Clean task in the project, e.g. by adding this to your .csproj (under the root element, e.g. before `</Project>`):

```
  <Target Name="CleanWcfProject" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)\WcfService\WcfService.csproj" Targets="Clean" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)" />
  </Target>
```

I'm not sure why you're running MSBuild on the WcfService.csproj project either, since you could simply add it as a project reference (right-click > Add Reference > Solution), which would cause MSBuild to automatically build the project upon seeing that its outputs are cleared.

**If your dependent project is in another Solution**

If this is the case, then the Clean should work with a relative path, but adding a ProjectReference may not be desirable/possible (you can still add the dependency to your solution, even if it's in another solution, but often this isn't possible/feasible because of lots of other dependencies).

If so, then simply add the build target as well,

```
  <Target Name="CleanWcfProject" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\WcfService\WcfService.csproj" Targets="Clean;Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)" />

  </Target>
```

Comment: I agree that the pre-build event isn't ideal.  The code solution is set to build the WcfService project, but the "smart" Build that happens when running a client doesn't always to the trick.  Which is why I manually wrote the pre-build event to do a "Clean" and build.  The generic path and Clean task in your post is very helpful.  I wasn't aware of that at all.  I found an msdn article to help me with the details.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx  This feels like the right solution.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to Al-Muhandis for getting me on the right track for this.  In summary, a Rebuild of the WCF Service project fixes my problem 100% of the time.  The pre-build event in my initial question was a very hacky way of doing this.  A simple Clean isn't enough as I get this error with just a Clean:

> The requested service, 'http://localhost:53934/EdmVendService/EdmVendor.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

My final solution was to add this block of XML to the csproj file.  I just used notepad to edit it.

```
<Target Name="RebuildWcfProject" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)\WcfService\WcfService.csproj" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)" />
</Target>
```

Here is the bottom of the csproj file after my change.

[image]

Hope this may be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this alternative settings for your project. Right Click on your web project. Select Properties and then Select the Web tab. Configure your Visual Studio as below.

[image]

Also Right Click on the Project and Select Set as Start Up Project as below
[image]

Then lastly Right Click on the home page, e.g. or the page you wish to start up first e.g. index.html, and Set As Start Page as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Most of our web client applications are set up that way.  They always fire up fine.  It is the backend web service that the client references within the solution which is the problem.  The client could be anything from a WPF app to a console app to a web client.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both console app and web app in the same solution, please try this, right on solution. Select properties and set the Start up Projects to Multiple startup projects as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice screenshot.  I will try that.

Comment: That seems to just start multiple clients at the same time.  The problem is with the backend service not firing up property in IIS Express.

Comment: If IIS Express is not starting and you have tried everything else, I would recommend un-installing and re-installing your visual studio. IIS Express is built in Visual Studio. That way you get default configuration out of the box and you should theoretical be fine